# How can data schema be rejected before the mongodb connection is made by node.js and mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I don't understand a specific asynchronous javascript code: I have a very simple few lines of javascript running by node.js where I query a local mongoDB, on the main lines it does this:

- require mongoose
- a promise to connect to the db

```
mongoose.connect("...url to my local mongoDB...")
     .then(console.log("Connected to DB..."))
```

- create a schema
- create a model from schema
- define an async function to create a new object, save it as document in mongoDB and console.log the result returned after the attempt to save the document.

What I don't understand is the order of the console.log("Connect to DB") and console.log(result from document.save()): indeed, when there are no error on saving, the order seems ok: i have first the "Connected to DB..." then the returned saved document:

[image]

But when there is a data validation error for not respecting some requirements, then the "Connected to DB" is printed after the "Connected to DB":

[image]

Regarding the structure of the code, I don't understand why the "Connected to the DB..." is printed after the print of the Error. I suspect ansynchronous code to be the reason but i don't understand why. This very simple few lines of code come from the "Programming with Mosh" course where we can see the exact same behavior on his console.

A little bit more code details:

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose")
    mongoose
      .connect(my_mongo_db_url)
      .then(() => console.log("Connected to DB"))
      .catch(err => console.log("Could not connect to DB"))
    
    const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ...course schema... })
    const Course= mongoose.model("Course", courseSchema )
    
    async function createCourse(){
      const course = new Course({ ...new course values... })
      try { const result = await course.save()}
      catch (err) { console.log(err.message)}
    }
    
    createCourse()
```

Comment: The data can be *validated* prior to a connection to the database being available, because the schema is provided, but can't possibly be *saved* prior to connecting.

Comment: which line of your code throws the validation error? since `courseSchema =` and `Course=` and `course = ` will all be executed in full before the actual code that performs the connection in `connect` even has a chance to begin

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ok I get it, the db error is not returned by the db engine but by node itself validating or not my data, and since the whole index.js is asynchronous, the createCourse() and its inner validation is executed (and rejected) before the connection to the db is made. Ok thanks. But in that case, since the whole index.js is asynchrnous, when there are no error, how the course.save() in createCourse() is not executed before the connection to the db is made (and so I would have an error like "no db connection yet")

Comment: @JaromandaX, the error comes from the try/catch of the await course.save() in the createCourse()

Comment: The call to course.save may be executed before the connection is made, but its internal implementation waits for the connection: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering

Comment: Thanks a lot @jonrsharpe, now it's clear, mongoose buffering waits for a connection. And this problem made me also understand that the whole index.js is asynchronous! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy here the @jonrsharpe comment that answered my question:

"The call to course.save may be executed before the connection is made, but its internal implementation waits for the connection: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering"